# Open multiple info buffers in Emacs

Tags: emacs, buffer

Is it possible to open more than one `info` buffer in Emacs? I used `C-h i` to open `info` and started reading the section I was interested in. While reading, I wanted to refer to another `info` section -- using `C-h i` a second time does not open a second `info` buffer. How can this be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Help for the `info` command says (get help with F1 f info):

```
A numeric prefix argument selects an Info buffer with the prefix
number appended to the Info buffer name.
```

So, open a first `info` window as usual, then open another info window by typing (for example):

M-2 M-x info

Now you have 2 independent info windows, the second one called `*info*<2>`.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the help for `info` before posting the question, but the help included with my version of Emacs did not explain it as well as what you posted above, so now I understand how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Split the window using `C-X-2`, to split horizontally or `C-X-3` to split vertically. that way you can have two panes showing the same buffer. You can get back to a single pane using `C-X-1`.

[image]

Comment: I tried that before posting my question. When I move to the second buffer (`C-x o`) and then navigate elsewhere in `info` (by pressing `^` for example), *both* buffers change. Your solution simply shows the *same* `info` section in two buffers. I would like to be able to view *another* `info` section in the second `info` buffer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, if you navigate using the links both buffers will change. I thought you wanted to look at different parts of _the same page_.

Answer (score 1):

The Info manual provides more information about the issue than the built-in documentation.

`M-x info-display-manual` is a convenient command. For more information, look at the [Emacs Info Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/info/Create-Info-buffer.html#Create-Info-buffer), chapter "Advanced", section "Advanced Info Commands", subsection "Create Info Buffer".

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `M-n` bound to `clone-buffer` to clone current `*info*` buffer.